# MsgBox prompt from Form_Close event displaying during other sub(s)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm building a database for work, and have a MsgBox prompt on the `Form_Close()` event to alert users that the data in the form will be lost, then upon clicking OK it runs `DoCmd.RunCommand acUndo`.

The problem I have is that some of the fields in the form have the property `Field.Visible = False` depending on the input in other fields.

Upon saving the record, the form doesn't reset the `Field.Visible = False` to `= True` unless the form is closed and reopened, which I've written into the `SaveButton_Click` event. Thus, upon saving a record, users are being alerted that their data will not be saved.

I've tried several approaches, with either the same result, or that it doesn't display the MsgBox at all.

Any help/guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: Rather than resetting the `Visible` property of your fields by closing & re-opening the form, why not set the `Visible` property of the appropriate fields as part of your code for the `SaveButton_Click` event?

Comment: Thank you @LeeMac, that would work, though there are several fields who's <Visible> property changes at different times based on several other fields' <After_Update> property. It's not straightforward to me how to only reset the <Visible> property for the fields that had changed during data entry.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are currently resetting the `Visible` property by closing & re-opening the form, an initial state for the `Visible` property for all controls on the form is known (the properties as they appear in the form design).

Therefore, rather than closing & re-opening the form to reset these properties (and consequently triggering the `Form_Close` event as an unwanted byproduct), set the `Visible` property for all controls on the form to their original values (per the form design) as part of your `SaveButton_Click` event.

---

Addressing your question from the comments:

> *though there are several fields who's `Visible` property changes at different times based on several other fields' `After_Update` property. It's not straightforward to me how to only reset the `Visible` property for the fields that had changed during data entry*

You don't need to only reset the `Visible` property for the controls whose `Visible` property has changed: simply reset the property for all relevant controls on your form. If the `Visible` property for a control is already `True` and hasn't been changed by the `After_Update` event, changing it to `True` as part of your `SaveButton_Click` event will not cause a problem.

Comment: So, if I have controls set up as such:    Private Sub Status_AfterUpdate()    If Status.Value = "Valid" Then    Me.Travel_Date.Visible = False   [...] Else Me.Travel_Date.Visible = True. Then in my SaveButton_Click() sub just set the visible condition I want equal to the condition AFTER the 'Else'? Or I guess I can just set it to how I want it to look upon opening the form to begin with. I'm new to coding so this is a challenge learning all this as I go.  I do appreciate the suggestion, and will definitely test this out when I get back to work.

Comment: @k.bratt *"Or I guess I can just set it to how I want it to look upon opening the form to begin with"* <-- this :) Good luck with the coding, let us know how you get on.